# Continuous JavaScript Testing

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration

Does anyone know of a good JavaScript testing tool which integrates automated testing with your Testing Framework of Choice. I am aware of TestSwarm (which is not automated testing) and Travis-CI (which isn't really available for closed-source projects).

Any other ones out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/):

Its test can either be generated by its IDE, or can be written in high level languages such as Java, PHP, etc.

Its can be instantiated from a Command-Line.

Its can be integrated with continuous-integration servers like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (In-build plugin).

The fact, that it can be instantiated from command-line (preferably written in java), makes it integrable by any CI Server

Answer (score 1):

Two that I know of (although I'm not sure they are really meant for this purpose...) are [Simple Test js](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletest-js/) and the MIT project [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/).  Sikuli is great for making a cursor click on things and test out the user interactions.  Neither one of these naturally will integrate well with your testing framework of choice but they will certainly allow you to write unit tests.  Hopefully someone else will know of a better solution.